# Pi Product Notation from some number up to $\infty$

Tags: infinite-product

Does it mean when

$\displaystyle\prod_{x=b}^{\infty}f(x) = 0$,

there must be at least 1 number ( $a$ ) between $b$ and $\infty$ inclusive such that $f(a) = 0$?

Comment: I wouldn't say $\infty$ inclusive.

Comment: You recieved two answers to your question. If any is what you were looking for, you should accept it, or otherwise explain what is still missing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it just means that

$$\lim_{B\to\infty} \prod_{x=b}^B f(x) = 0$$

which is true, for example, for the function $f$ which is constantly equal to $\frac{1}{2}$ for all $x$.

Comment: What if the function is not constant and not all values of f(x) is between -1 and 1? Would there still be a situation which it equals zero without a number where f(number) = 0?

Comment: @HyunsooKim Of course, as long as the limit I describe is $0$. For example, if $f(x)$ varies between $2$ and $\frac14$, then the limit will still be $0$.

Answer (score 1):

If a function $|f(x)|$  is less than $1$ when $x\in [a,\infty)$ then $$\prod_{x=b}^\infty f(x)=\begin{cases}0 & a\le b\\\prod_{x=b}^{a-1} f(x)\times\prod_{x=a}^\infty f(x)=\prod_{x=b}^{a-1} f(x)\times0=0 & a>b\end{cases}$$
so even if no $f(x)$ is $0$ the product can be equal $0$